# Do stray dogs ever bite people or only trained “security” dogs bite?

Tags: dogs

I want know do stray dogs ever bite people or only trained “security” dogs bite? Because i'm scared of dogs and in my place there are many stray dogs.

Comment: All dogs might bite. Most dogs don't bite without cause. In your case, being visibly afraid actually increases the chance a dog might bite, so even if afraid, acting confident and unafraid while avoiding a dog is the best way to act. It might make you less afraid of dogs, even.

Comment: A more advanced topic: Also remember that the mouth is the closest thing a dog has to a hand, and some may grab without intending to bite.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer to this question is yes, but the longer one is fairly logical if you think about it a bit. Basically, just about any animal may attack or bite a human based on one or more conditions such as:

1. Is afraid and backed into a corner thus leaving it no real option but to attack rather than flee.
2. Is extremely hungry and has now become more reckless in attempting to get food. Alternately, they have food and are concerned that you may try to take it from them. Hunger is a powerful motivator.
3. Is sick or injured and you get too close. Vets learn handling techniques for dealing with animals in this condition, but even very tame ones can react with teeth and claws when you attempt to help them.
4. You react with more extreme fear. Running with your back to the animal is leaving you vulnerable and so they may chase.
5. You enter their territory (e.g. den or hiding spot) and they're now defending it from intrusion.

There's probably even more conditions, but those are some I can think of. At the heart of it all, it's best to avoid strays and unknown animals regardless of your anxiety over it. Most animals will avoid direct interactions with humans given a choice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Dogs do bite. All dogs, given the right provocation. Much like how if you push a person hard enough, they'll punch you.

Well trained dogs are like well behaved people - they'll take a lot more provoking before they lash out.

Any random dog *might* bite you, but very few will for no reason - attacking puts them at risk too, so they're not going to pick a fight unless there's a reason for it. This goes for strays just as much as dogs you don't know. But on the flip side - you'll rarely know if a stray has been abused for some reason, and therefore what they'll perceive as a threat.

One of the saddest things I saw when I was last at a dog sanctuary - an older gentleman walking around on a stick, clearly looking for a new companion. The dogs there were getting worked up, and it wasn't until I saw one or two cringing that I worked out the problem - they had been taught to be afraid of walking sticks, and they were reacting by acting aggressive.

However, almost invariably - because that's their nature - dogs 'threaten' first. They'll bark or growl to warn you off. This is how they'd 'do things' in the wild - they don't kill each other over food, they'll challenge and only fight if desperate.

So in short - you do have to be careful with strays. But don't be overly fearful, because it's actively counterproductive for them to be randomly violent. The caution is because you're never going to be entirely sure what they've learned is 'dangerous'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between animals that have been abandoned or escaped from previous owners and those that are born without contact with humans and are feral.

Many stray animals are born and raised without habituation with humans can be feral and might be dangerous if instigated. You should never approach a stray animal that you are not familiar with, especially one that appears angry or fearful, and you shouldn't allow any children or other pets to approach them in that situation too. If you're not familiar with the animal, you can't guarantee they don't have transmittable parasites or diseases, even if this is rare.

If you are concerned about the safety of the animal or those around it, contact a shelter for information on what to do. If you're remotely unsure about the animal's behavior, then for both your and the animal's safety, it's a job for professionals.

Also, do not approach or try to take home animals that aren't domesticated; there is a big difference between a 'tame' animal and a 'domesticated' animal. And keeping them as pets might be illegal in your area, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The more you act scared and fearful, the more chances you are going to be beaten. Usually, dogs won't bite without a reason. But if you show intense fear that will trigger the dog. I know this because I have a friend who is extremely afraid of dogs...One day my two friends came home - one who is extremely scared and the other who is not. My dog is usually friendly to people (unless they touch my dog immediately). The way my dog treated my two friends was so different - which surprised me. He licked my other friend who was not scared, and to my intensely terrified friend, he kept on barking angrily. He didn't mind my unafraid friend to touch him and play with him, but to my extremely scared friend, it was impossible for my friend to go near my dog.

It really depends on how you act....I also know that when you are fearful, there is a certain scent that comes from humans. The dogs will easily smell that. So you should act confident.